# jQuery to make images clickable (wrap them in a href)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to make each image (that has a certain class) clickable?

I want jQuery to:

1. Read the `src` of the image.
2. Wrap the image with an `a href` that contains that src url.

```css
.clickable {
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/stay-and-play-at-home-with-popular-past-google-doodles-fischinger-2017-6753651837108768-s.png" class="clickable">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img.clickable").each(function(i){
  $(this).wrap(`<a href="${($(this).attr('src'))}"></a>`)
 })
})
```

```css
.clickable {
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/stay-and-play-at-home-with-popular-past-google-doodles-fischinger-2017-6753651837108768-s.png" class="clickable">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
$("img.clickable").wrap("<a href='" + $('img').attr('src') + "'></a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2020/stay-and-play-at-home-with-popular-past-google-doodles-fischinger-2017-6753651837108768-s.png" class="clickable">
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I tie it to a classname? It doesn't work with `.clickable`, for some reason.

Comment: @Maximus I have added the classname to my answer. It's not working?

Comment: @Maximus Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want something like this:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {....})
```

let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

can you brief the scenario, not getting your point?

got your point: -
you can use the following to wrap all the images having class clickable with and and with href as the image src

```
$('.clickable').each(function(){
    src = $this.attr('src');
    $this.wrap("<a href='" + src  + "'></a>");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var url=$(".clickable").attr("src");
$("a").attr("href", url);
```